# How can user diverted into different page if he login first time...?

Tags: php, ajax

My simple question is that i want to give different page to the user if he/she going login first time after registration ..I have no idea which kind privileges would implement kindly suggest links or idea's

Comment: Yes, they can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: That's not a simple question especially when you throw out random tags like php and ajax and don't show any php or ajax.

Comment: I  just using PHP .but as i said i don't have an idea how would it works...if you have an example or some thing you can throw here..

Answer (score 0):

You can have a column called first_login in user table. while user registration time set the value to 1.
In login time check whether the first_login field has value 1, if its has 1,then redirect to  different page.
In that page set value of first_login to 0.